# How do I eliminate the breaks in a 3D plot with a Max or Min function?

Tags: plotting

Whenever I make a 3D plot using the `Max` or `Min` functions, I get breaks in the plot when it switches from one expression in `Max` or `Min` to the other. How can I eliminate these breaks to get one continuous surface?

The particular example I want to make work is this:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t],
  Max[r^2 Cos[t]^2 - 1.06^2, 0] + Max[r^2 Sin[t]^2 - 1.92^2, 0]},
  {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 3.4}, Mesh->None, Boxed->False, Axes->None]
```

which produces this:

[image: surface showing breaks in plot]

but it is possible to reproduce the effect with simpler expressions like `Plot3D[Max[x, 1], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]`.

---

I've checked that occurs with Mathematica 7 and 8 on Windows and Linux.

Comment: David, what system are you on? I couldn't reproduce this on Win7 M9.

Comment: Version 8 on Linux (Gentoo). Let me try v7 and v9 (if I can get it to work) to see if it does the same.

Comment: Ah, this is indeed a duplicate. I didn't find that question when I was looking for prior work.

Comment: It's not always easy to find them, even when I remember the question!

Comment: David, if you unaccept the answer below, I will delete it. (The system does not allow deletion of accepted answers.)

Comment: @kguler done, although are you sure? I do think in its current form it's certainly a good answer.

Comment: thanks David. Szabolcs' answer in the linked q/a covers all the points made in my answer.