# Why does Plot leave gaps in the graph of a continuous function?

Tags: plotting

I have plotted the overlapping area of the UnitBox and the triangle function as:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Integrate[
       Piecewise[{{1, -0.5 <= x < 0.5}, {0, Not[-0.5 <= x < 0.5]}}] 
       Piecewise[{{x + 1 - a, -1 + a <= x <= 0 + a}, {-x + 1 + a, 0 + a <= x <= 1 + a}}],
   {x, -Infinity, +Infinity}]], 
{a, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

However, the result has gaps as you can see in the plot:

[image]

Why is this happening if the function is continuous?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can use `Exclusions -> None`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4797/12

Comment: possible duplicate(s):[Plot showing discontinuity where it shouldn't](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13657/125) and [How do I eliminate the breaks in a 3D plot with a Max or Min function?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19271/125)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. However I knew that Exclusions->None solved the problem. I wanted to know the reason for those "exclusions" and Belisarius gave it to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Plot[]` is excluding the discontinuities in the second derivative:

```
f[x_, a_] := Integrate[
                Piecewise[{{1, -0.5 <= x < 0.5}, {0, Not[-0.5 <= x < 0.5]}}] 
                Piecewise[{{x + 1 - a, -1 + a <= x <= 0 + a}, {-x + 1 + a, 0 + a <= x <= 1 + a}}],
             {x, -Infinity, +Infinity}]

Plot[Evaluate[D[f[x, a], a]], {a, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As @b,gatessucks mentioned in a comment, using `Exclusions->None` solves the issue:

```
Plot[Evaluate[f[x, a]], {a, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This is the answer I was looking for. I knew that I could "fill the gaps" with "Exclusions" Option. However, I wanted to know the reason.