# Mathematica plots a discontinuity in piecewise function that does not exist

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction

I have the following function defined:

```
IntImpTri[r1_, r2_, r_] := 
  Piecewise[{
    {((4/((r2 - r1)^2)) ((r^2 - r1^2)/2 - r1 (r - r1))), 
     r >= r1 && r < ((r1 + r2)/2)}, 
    {(1/2 - (2/((r2 - r1)^2)) (r^2 - ((r1 + r2)/2)^2) + 
      (4/((r2 - r1)^2)) r2 (r - ((r1 + r2)/2))), 
     r >= ((r1 + r2)/2) && r < r2}, 
    {1, r >= r2}}, 0];
```

I am using *Mathematica 9* and I do not understand why, when I try to plot this function, which is the integral function of a triangle pulse, the figure shows an interruption in the line.

If I try the following command: `Plot[IntImpTri[0, 4, r], {r, -1, 5}]`, I get the following output:

[image]

There is a discontinuity around `x=2` but the piecewise covers everything!

Comment: I am using Mathematica under Unix...

Comment: I am not sure exactly why it is missing this point (must be something with how Plot is decided to recurse), but try increasing the PlotPoints to specify how many initial sample points to use:
     `Plot[IntImpTri[0, 4, r], {r, -1, 5}, PlotPoints -> 300]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot showing discontinuity where it shouldn't](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13657/plot-showing-discontinuity-where-it-shouldnt).  Also a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19877/why-does-plot-leave-gaps-in-the-graph-of-a-continuous-function.  For more information, do a [search](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=piecewise+discontinuity).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Plot[IntImpTri[0, 4, r], {r, -1, 5}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

The problem is usually caused by discontinuities in the derivatives